# Ajax Onclick Event is not going to the Server side

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I have following code in html with a HTML button ..

```
               Name*:<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
               <br />
               Your Email*:<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
               <br />
               Phone Number:<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" />
              <br />
               Mobile*:&<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" value="" />
               <br />
               Country*:<input type="text" name="country" id="country" value="" />
               <br />
               Please Describe About Requirements:
               <textarea id="TextArea1" name="S1" rows="1"></textarea>

                 <br /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Now here i want to do a ajax click event to send data to the server side but i am not getting any XHR while seeing at the server side code neither i am able to debug.I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Ajax Code..

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {

             $('#submit').click(function (evt) {
                 evt.preventDefault();
                 var name = $('#name').val();
                 var email = $('#email').val();
                 var phone = $('#phone').val();
                 var mobile = $('#mobile').val();
                 var country = $('#country').val();
                 var textarea = $('#TextArea1').val();

                 var URL = 'getGriddahico.ashx?name=' + $('#name').val() + '&email=' + $('#email').val() + '&phone=' + $('#phone').val() + '&mobile=' + $('#mobile').val() + '&country=' + $('#country').val() + '&textarea=' + $('#textarea').val();

                 alert("hii");

             });

         });

         </script>
```

While i am able to get Hii in the alert box..
Please help me..

Comment: Where is the ajax call in your code?

Comment: You want to do ajax without writing code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the ajax call itself.

```
var URL = 'getGriddahico.ashx?name=' + $('#name').val() + '&email=' + $('#email').val() 
           + '&phone=' + $('#phone').val() + '&mobile=' + $('#mobile').val() + 
         '&country=' + $('#country').val() + '&textarea=' + $('#TextArea1').val();

$.ajax({
 url:URL,
 type: "GET",// default is GET (as you are sending data as parameter)
 success:function(result){}
});
```

Comment: @user3699193, what is the id of your textarea? I think its TextArea1.

Comment: Ok Now i have changed that to  <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>

Comment: @user3699193. Please do not change the id to `textarea`. Keep as `TextArea1`. Change the URL value `'&textarea=' + $('#TextArea1').val()`

Answer (score 0):

Use this kind of AJAX call inside your click function

`$.ajax({
      url: "test.html",
      context: document.body
    }).done(function() {
      $( this ).addClass( "done" );
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Do these modifications

```
var formData= {name:"abc",age:"15"}; // add more parameters like this which you want to send on server.

$.ajax({
    url : "getGriddahico.ashx",
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        //data - response from server
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your html in `form` tags eg:

```
<form id="form1"> </form>
```

And change your jquery to submit event of the form instead of click:

```
$('#form1').submit(function (evt) { ... });
```

And of course you are missing the AJAX itself...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this and will help you....

```
var URL = 'getGriddahico.ashx?name=' + $('#name').val() + '&email=' + $('#email').val() + '&phone=' + $('#phone').val() + '&mobile=' + $('#mobile').val() + '&country=' + $('#country').val() + '&textarea=' + $('#textarea').val();

$.ajax({
   url:URL,
   success:function(){
       alert("Hii")
   }
});
```

Comment: I am getting textarea='undefined' error in the URL How to remove this